# How to get model from other tag attributes in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have following html

```
 <input class="form-check-input" data-fieldId="79" ng-model="test1"  type="text" name="test1">


<input class="form-check-input" data-fieldId="80" ng-model="test2"  type="text" name="test2">
```

I have  data-fieldId in controller. I need to find the input element through field id and its value in angular way.

Answer (score -1):

i am not understanding your question exactly but You can try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>

            <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

              <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.6/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
              <style>
              .grid {
      width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
    }
              </style>
        </head>
        <body>


      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userController">
        <input class="form-check-input" data-fieldId="79" ng-model="test1" ng-change="textchanged()" type="text" name="test1">


        <input class="form-check-input" data-fieldId="80" ng-model="test2" ng-change="textchanged()" type="text" name="test2"> {{result1}} {{result2}}
        </div>

            <script>
       var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"]);

         app.controller('userController', function ($scope) {

         $scope.textchanged = function(){
          $scope.result1 = $scope.test1;
          $scope.result2 = $scope.test2
         }

        });
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Why using ng-change there is no need for this ?? i just need to find out the input element from data-fieldId

Comment: input element means the data what ever you give in textbox right ??

Comment: Yes need to find the element and its value the model is dynamic.

Comment: when you enter value in text box angular should get to know that value has been changed or you should write the watcher for it.
thats why written textchanged() event